# Optimized thumbnail creating for articles with active storage hosted on AWS S3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, aws-sdk, rails-activestorage, minimagick

I am building a blog post, in the article model, I use aws-sdk and minimagik for upload images. I have a method to get the url of thumbnail to show to every article like this

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
    has_one_attached :post_thumbnails

    def thumb_url(width=200, heigh=200)
      return unless post_thumbnails.attached?
      image_dimension = "#{width}x#{heigh}"
      Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.rails_representation_url(post_thumbnails.variant(
        combine_options: [
          [:resize, "#{image_dimension}^"],
          [:gravity, "center"],
          [:crop, "#{image_dimension}+0+0"],
          [:strip, true],
          [:quality, "70"],
          [:repage, nil], [:+, nil], # +repage
          [:distort, nil], [:+, "Perspective"]
        ]
      ).processed, only_path: true)
    end
  end
```

I am struggling to find the better way for getting the thumbnail url or just getting resize image to reduce storage on S3, actually I don't need to use the original version of the thumbnail

Can anyone help me to get better solution so that I can get different thumbnail size once I pass the size, I know the `ActiveStorage::Variant` to get different sizes of image `activestorage`.